# Is there a way to remove a Service Activity from Calendar area in a Microsoft Dynamics CRM Workplace?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I need to remove a Service Activity link which is located on the right-hand side of Calendar area under the “Create a New:” section in Workplace. However, I see no way of doing it other than changing /workplace/home_calendar.aspx, which I'm not allowed to do. Is there any other possible way?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I've recently asked myself the same question, but didn't find any supported way to do it.

Comment: Apperently this is impossile. At least, that's the response I've got from msdn.

Comment: Was that response something you got from email, or rather from the MSDN site?

Comment: I've got it from a response on msdn forum. I tend to believe it since I've got no other responces either here or there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in a supported way. It is part of the default entities, which you can't remove. Normally you would deny the permission for unneeded entities. This is not applicable for the service activity, since you only could grant permission for 'activity' which bundles all activity types.

Please see also my answer at [Disable Service Actity in CRM 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817322/disable-service-actity-in-crm-2011/8189659#8189659)