# Disable Service Actity in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to disable the 'Service Activity'. I turn off the privileges of Read, Create, Write and Delete at Setting - Administration - Security Role - Service Management Tab - Service (entity) as None.

Now, Service Activity is disable at all levels except at Workplace - My Work - Activities - New Activity - Service Activity. Any idea, how to disable this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could always remove the navigational item from the sitemap. That would remove it, but the best way is remove the permissions (like you did).

I would also check to see what other roles you/that user has to verify that no other role/team has permissions to that entity.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deny the privilege for the service activity. There is only a permission for *all* activity types.

You removed the permission for the service entity, which defines a service that your organization could supply. This is *not* the serive activity. A service is delievered with a service activity.